# Ignite Authentication - REST API ERROR in response

Tags: authentication, ignite, rest, gridgain, sqlline

```
{"successStatus":2,"error":"The user name or password is incorrect [userName=[testuser]]","sessionToken":null,"response":null}
```

Getting this REST API response on triggering authorization call for Ignite with following command:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version&ignite.login=[testuser]&ignite.password=[password]"
```

I have already created this user via sqlline interface of ignite with

```
create user "testuser" with PASSWORD 'password';
```

this command.
Authentication is enabled in my cluster configuration file. Please tell me how I can get rid of this error, where I have mistaken or missed any step.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try with uppercase like [TESTUSER]

Comment: it's showing same error